# Using CSS add box shadow to every line of text

Tags: css, word-wrap

I made a notebook with CSS using `box-shadow` and `margin` -- example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0j6tycfd/)

The problem is that when a line break occurs, the notebook row gets bigger, so it no longer looks like a notebook.  Is there any way to make the line appear below every row of text?

Daniel

**HTML**

```
<div id="receitas">
  <br />
  <div class="ingredientes">
    <div class="titulo">
      <p>Ingredientes</p>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li><p class="subtitulo">Massa: </p></li>
      <li><p>2 colheres de (chá) de bicarbonato</p></li>
      <li><p>1 e ½ xícaras de (chá) de Leite Porto Real Tipo A, não pode ser desnatado</p></li>
      <li><p>1 xícara de (chá) de chocolate em pó</p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#receitas {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Crafty Girls', cursive;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 410px;
}

#receitas .ingredientes {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 2px 2px 0 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#receitas .ingredientes p {
    margin: 0 0px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}

#receitas .ingredientes .titulo {
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    margin: -13px 10px;
}

#receitas .ingredientes .subtitulo {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#receitas .ingredientes .titulo p {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    transform: rotate(-4deg);
    background: url(/images/agronelli/alimentos/receitas/fundotitulo.png) no-repeat top left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
}

#receitas .ingredientes ul {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 5%;

}

#receitas .ingredientes li {
    padding: 3px 2px 0 35px;
    margin: 0 !important;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #444;
    margin-left: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    /*border-radius: 3px;*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1.532px 1px 0 #a1d7f3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1.532px 1px 0 #a1d7f3;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 -1.532px 1px 0 #a1d7f3;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 -1.532px 1px 0 #a1d7f3;
    box-shadow: 0 1.532px 1px 0 #a1d7f3;
}

#receitas .ingredientes li p{
    border: 1px solid #ef9d99;
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

#receitas .ingredientes li:first-child {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1.532px 1px 0 #a1d7f3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1.532px 1px 0 #a1d7f3;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 -1.532px 1px 0 #a1d7f3;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 -1.532px 1px 0 #a1d7f3;
    box-shadow: 0 -1.532px 1px 0 #a1d7f3;
    height: 25px;
}

#receitas .ingredientes li:last-child {
    height: 45px;
}

#receitas .ingredientes li:nth-child(2) {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: -6px !important;
}

#receitas .modo-preparo .titulo {
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}

#receitas .modo-preparo .titulo p {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    transform: rotate(-4deg);
    background: url(/images/agronelli/alimentos/receitas/fundotitulo.png) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin: 0 0;
    width: 200px;
}

#receitas .modo-preparo p {
    line-height: 21px;
}
```

Comment: Don't cheat. Just add code, like SO asks.

Comment: I'd suggest making a repeating image, setting the right line-height and sizing the div automatically to content with a repeating background.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce problem or error in the **question itself**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a repeating background image instead of `box-shadow`.
Here is a fiddle showing what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/9u7gc1wp/

Here we set a gradient background that is the blue color for a short while then transparent for the rest. It is then repeated and scaled to the right size.

```
#receitas .ingredientes ul {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 5%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(161,215,243,1) 8%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 95%,rgba(161,215,243,1) 100%);
    background-size: auto 27px; 
}
```

There were some other changes to your css that I made (mostly removing `box-shadow` code and padding/margins), so take a look at the fiddle to see everything that I changed. You may need to tweak the height of the background and the `line-height` to fit your real content.

What this looks like:

[image: Notebook]